# Can't pull state out of redux reducer: "Cannot read property 'tracks' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to pull some state from redux but get error:Cannot read property 'tracks' of undefined. Not sure where the error is originating from. 
here is the action:

```
export const getTracks = () => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get("/api/tracks/all")
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_TRACKS,
         payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_TRACKS,
        payload: null
     })
   );
 };
```

here is the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  track: {}
};

 export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case GET_TRACKS:
   return{
     ...state, 
     tracks: action.payload, 
     loading: false
   }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here is the component where Im trying to pull the state from :

```
class Tracks extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getTracks();
  }
  render() {
    const {tracks, loading} = this.props.track;
    let trackItems;
Tracks.PropTypes = {
  getTracks: PropTypes.func.isRequired, 
  track: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  track: state.track
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getTracks}) (Tracks);
```

Kinda new to react/redux so not sure if im missing any code to show the full problem.

I have redux dev tools open in chrome and can see the state being populated with 'tracks' from Mlab but can't seem to pull that state out in the Tracks component with this line :

```
   const {tracks, loading} = this.props.track;
```

Comment: How are you configuring the store? Are you using `combineReducers` somewhere?

Comment: Looks like there are/could be several issues here. You have a default value for `track` in your reducer, but you are setting a value for `tracks` in your first case statement. put `console.log(state)` in your `mapStateToProps` to see the shape of your store.

Comment: I am using combineReducers, and how do I console.log(state) , its not liking that statement inside mapStateToProps func

Comment: Change the mapStateToProps function to use an explicit return.

Comment: Not sure how to do that

Comment: Like this `const mapStateToProps = (state) => { console.log(state); return {...}; }`

Comment: That logs all the seven tracks that are also present in the state of Redux dev tools in chrome

Comment: So I have the tracks in the state, just not sure why const {tracks} = this.props.track is coming up as undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187945/discussion-between-max-and-carlos-herrera).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is a spelling error in your mapStateToProps function. It should be **state.tracks**, not state.track.

It should be:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  track: state.tracks
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a type on your reducer based on your initial state prop

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case GET_TRACKS:
   return{
     ...state, 
     tracks: action.payload, // <--- should be track and not tracks
     loading: false
   }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

You will also need to access them inside your render like.

```
const {track, loading} = this.props.tracks; // Assuming you reducer is imported as tracks
```

If you plan to use the plural

Tracks Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  tracks: {}
};

 export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case GET_TRACKS:
   return{
     ...state, 
     tracks: action.payload, 
     loading: false
   }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Inside Tracks

```
class Tracks extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const {tracks: { tracks, loading }} = this.props;
    ...
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tracks: state.tracks
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you console log action.payload